# Transmissão com certificado digital c#

Tags: web-service, xml

Estou desenvolvendo uma rotina de transmissão de nota fiscal eletrônica de serviços em c#.

Já assinei as TAGS de acordo com o manual da prefeitura mas quando tento fazer a transmissão retorna este erro.

```
<MensagemRetorno>
      <Codigo>E504</Codigo>
      <Mensagem>O certificado digital do prestador de serviços é obrigatório.</Mensagem>
      <Correcao>Envie junto a requisição do serviço o certificado digital do prestador de serviços.</Correcao>
</MensagemRetorno>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas para ajudar quem estiver com o mesmo problema consegui enviar o certificado com o seguinte código

```
WsTeste.consulta ws = new WsTeste.consulta();
ws.Url = @"https://wsserver/securemath/math.asmx";
ws.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath));
Retorno = ws.consultarLote("teste", XMLAssinado.OuterXml);
```

Para maiores detalhe vejam este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa302408.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

O problema deve estar na string que você está enviando, que deve estar mal formatada, tente fazer o seguinte, primeiro formate sua string seguindo a documentação da prefeitura, fica mais ou menos como está abaixo, e cuidado, IISRetido tem que estar com S ou N e não 0 ou 1, se atente na documentação para tipo de Rps, etc.:

```
char pad = '0';  
string strDeAssinatura = tpRPS.ChaveRPS.InscricaoPrestador.ToString().PadLeft(8, pad) +
                tpRPS.ChaveRPS.SerieRPS.PadRight(5, ' ') +
                tpRPS.ChaveRPS.NumeroRPS.ToString().PadLeft(12, pad) +
                tpRPS.DataEmissao.ToString("yyyyMMdd").PadLeft(8, pad) +
                tpRPS.TributacaoRPS.ToString() +
                tpRPS.StatusRPS.ToString() +
                iisRetido +
                tpRPS.ValorServicos.ToString("N2", _enUS).Replace(".", "").ToString().PadLeft(15, pad) +
                tpRPS.ValorDeducoes.ToString("N2", _enUS).Replace(".", "").ToString().PadLeft(15, pad) +
                tpRPS.CodigoServico.ToString().PadLeft(5, pad) + 
                tomadorTipo +                                              
                tpRPS.CPFCNPJTomador.Item.PadLeft(14, pad);
```

Depois assine apenas essa string, você pode usar a função abaixo para isso: 
Depois jogue o valor em tpRPS.Assinatura e pronto.
Boa sorte.

```
private byte[] Assinatura(string strDeAssinatura)
{   
    KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
    KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data(_cert);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_cert.PublicKey.Key;
    keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData); 
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = _cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsaKey);
    RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
    SHA1Managed SHhash = new SHA1Managed();
    byte[] SignedHashValue = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(SHhash.ComputeHash(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(strDeAssinatura)));   
    return SignedHashValue;
}
```